# Spring Data MongoDB Credentials

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, openshift, spring-data

With Spring Data, I am trying to get a Mongo object that has username and password credentials.

I need to set this programmatically, rather than with XML

All of the examples that I have found use the deprecated system. I am looking for the current way to do this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
MongoClient connection = new MongoClient(host, port);
List<MongoCredential> credentialsList = connection.getCredentialsList();
credentialsList.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(
          userName,
          getDatabaseName(),
          password.toCharArray()
));
```

I don't really want to set the database here, since Spring Data already handles that elsewhere, but I don't see a way to get a MongoCredentials object without it.

Anyway, not being able to find a good example, or documentation that I can understand, this is my best guess for how to do it. However, it does not work. When the connection is used, it throws `exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: not authorized for query` I must be missing something, either an OpenShift requirement that I am unaware of, or a flaw in my credentials code.

Comment: Or are the deprecated examples exactly what I want, since OpenShift uses MongoDB 2.4, not 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get it working with this code:

```
ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(
                environmentHost, Integer.parseInt(environmentPort));

MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(
                environmentUserName,
                getDatabaseName(),
                environmentPassword.toCharArray());

MongoClient client =  new MongoClient(
                serverAddress, Arrays.asList(credential));
```

This requires the Java MongoDB drivers at at least version 2.13

Here is the section in my pom.xml that I ended up using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```